# Как пронумеровать каждый вывод print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, список, print

У меня есть функция, которая во время работы выводит в терминал:

```
print("...")
```

Мне нужно, чтобы каждый новый `print` нумеровался:

```
print ("[1]...")
```

Comment: покажите что у вас есть

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Встроенная функция [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) - именно то, что вам нужно!
Она возвращает кортежи с порядковым номером и очередным элементом:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']

>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```

нумерация может начитаться с заданного числа (0 по-умолчанию):

```
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

Для вашего случая:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
for i, m in enumerate(months, 1):  # начитать нумерацию с 1
   print(f'{i}: {m}')
```

На печать выведет:

```
1: January
2: February
3: March
4: April
5: May
6: June
7: July
8: August
9: September
10: October
11: November
12: December
```

или так:

```
print(f'[{i}] {m}')
```

выведет по вашему шаблону:

```
[1] January
[2] February
[3] March
[4] April
[5] May
[6] June
[7] July
[8] August
[9] September
[10] October
[11] November
[12] December
```

Answer (score 5):

Написать универсальное решение не так просто. Вместо функции `print` создадим функцию `eprint` (enumeration print), которая самостоятельно вставляет номер в начале каждой печати. Получается сложная конструкция с замыканиями, итераторами и передачей параметров с помощью `*args, **kwargs`:

```
import itertools

def make_eprint():
    c = itertools.count(start=1)
    
    def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs_copy = dict(kwargs)
        kwargs_copy.update(end=' ', flush=False)
        print(f'[{next(c)}]', **kwargs_copy)
        print(*args, **kwargs)

    return eprint

eprint = make_eprint()

eprint('Hello, world!')
eprint(1, 2, 3, sep='-')
eprint(1, 2, 3, sep='-', end='\n\n')
eprint(1, 2, 3, end=' ')
eprint(1, 2, 3)
```

Результат:

```
[1] Hello, world!
[2] 1-2-3
[3] 1-2-3

[4] 1 2 3 [5] 1 2 3
```

В последней строке виден дефект, который не устраняется просто.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с декоратором:

```py
def super_print(f):
    m = [0]
    foo = print
    def helper(x):
        m[0] = f(m[0])
        foo(f'[{m[0]}]: {x}')
    return helper

@super_print
def print(n):
    return n+1

print("Monday")
print("Tuesday")
print("Wednesday")
```

Вывод:

```
[1]: Monday
[2]: Tuesday
[3]: Wednesday
```