# Как пронумеровать элементы списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

```py
    def click_element(url):                                                                                                         #
        driver.get(url)                                                                                                             #Перейти по URL
        sleep(3)                                                                                                                    #Ждём 3 сек
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn_green_white_innerfade.btn_medium.market_noncommodity_buyorder_button").click()       #Найти кнопку "Заказать"
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buy_commodity_input_price").click()                                                       #Нажать на поле указа стоимости
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buy_commodity_input_price").send_keys(u'\ue009' + u'\ue003')                              #Очистить строку стоимость
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buy_commodity_input_price").send_keys(cost)                                               #Добавить свою стоимость
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buy_commodity_input_quantity").click()                                                    #Нажать на поле указа кольчевства
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buy_commodity_input_quantity").send_keys(u'\ue014' + u'\ue009' + u'\ue003')               #Очистить строку количевство
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buy_commodity_input_quantity").send_keys(suma)                                            #Добавить свою сумму
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buyorder_dialog_accept_ssa").click()                                                      #Ставим галку "Подтвердить сделку"
        driver.find_element_by_id("market_buyorder_dialog_purchase").click()                                                        #Заказываем
        sleep(15)                                                                                                                   #Ждём 15 сек
        print(URL)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                      #
        links = [link1, link2, link3, link4, link5, link6, link7, link8, link9, link10                                              #Ссылки которые будет менятся в строке 154
    , link11, link12, link13, link14, link15, link16, link17, link18, link19, link20
    , link21, link22, link23, link24, link25, link26, link27, link28, link29, link30
    , link31, link32, link33, link34, link35, link36, link37, link38, link39, link40
    , link41, link42, link43, link44, link45, link46, link47, link48, link49, link50
    , link51, link52, link53, link54, link55, link56, link57, link58, link59, link60
    , link61, link62, link63, link64, link65, link66, link67, link68, link69, link70
    , link71, link72, link73, link74, link75, link76, link77, link78, link79, link80
    , link81, link82, link83, link84, link85, link86, link87, link88, link89, link90
    , link91, link92, link93, link94, link95, link96, link97, link98, link99, link100
    , link101, link102, link103, link104, link105, link106, link107, link108, link109
    , link110, link111]
        for link in links:                                                                                                          #
            click_element(link)
```

Comment: в смысле пронумеровать ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
links = [
    'link1', 
    'link2', 
    'link3', 
    'link42'
    ]
```

"Задача вывести номер ссылки с которой щас производятся действия": [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) на каждой итерации возвращает кортеж (i, link), просто печатайте i там, где нужно:

```
for i, link in enumerate(links, 1):                                                                                                          
        print(f'{i}: {link}')
```

выведет:

```
1: link1
2: link2
3: link3
4: link42
```

ps [ассоциация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219355/420098)